# Sending commands through ssh using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a project in which i need to send ssh commands to device using ip address, username and password through vb.net.

One of the commands i need to send is: `/usr/share/qt-4.6.0/sendqtevent -kqt 0x01000012 -ks 0x25`

Does vb.net even support ssh connections and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You need [SSH.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET) for that. No SSH in .Net.

Comment: Isn't SSH.NET for C#?

Comment: C# is Dot Net, just like VB.Net